# ERROR: query has no destination for result data Need to return float

Tags: postgresql-9.2

> I want to get the type of a point's M coordinate, and use the method of ST_M and ST_line_interpolate_point and so on, and I can get the correct result through the SQL. Now I want to put it into the pl/pgsql function, it always has the error, please help! Thanks!

```
create or replace function point_to_M1(x float, y float,z integer)
    returns float AS
    $$
    DECLARE
        geom geometry;
    begin
      select testo.geom from testo where lineid=z;
      return st_astext(ST_line_interpolate_point(st_geometryN(geom,1),st_line_locate_point(st_geometryN(geom,1),'point(x y)')));
    end;
    $$
    language plpgsql;
```

> And this function doesn't exist the error, but when I use this function, it has the error.

`select point_to_m1(80,0,0) from testo;`

> The error is:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function point_to_m1(double precision,double precision,integer) line 5 at SQL statementter code here
```

> How could I slove this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is this line:
`select testo.geom from testo where lineid=z;`

This is a standard select statement, which doesn't actually tell Postgresql to **store** the result in any variable - or in Postgresql's words, there's no destination for it.

It also means that on the next line, where you try to use your variable `geom` it would still be empty.

Try this:

```
select geom INTO geom from testo where lineid=z;
```

Here, the first `geom` is the field name, and `INTO geom` tells Postgresql to store the result in the variable `geom` which you declared previously.

For clarity, you might want to rename your variable, because it looks a bit confusing having the variable name the same as the field.

Here's the reference page: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-SELECT-INTO

Comment: Thanks! Through your method, I get the value of geom!